# meaning of the phrase "make someone less"?

Tags: meaning

It was in this [video](https://youtu.be/zn7Q0m_o-Xs). It is at 5 minute and 56 second. Here it goes:

> Everyone around us may have been trying to do their best to us children, and yet we have ended up now, as adults, nursing certain major hurts which continue to **make us so much less** than we might be.

Could you please rephrase the sentence for me so that I can understand what the speaker means t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make something or someone less is to diminish, to make that thing or person smaller in some way, or possibly to prevent its full growth. Things can be made physically smaller. With people the meaning tends to be figurative, meaning to reduce or inhibit their power or effectiveness, or their full attainment of these. As adults we nurse major hurts which prevent us from reaching our full potential as human beings.